# Excel Sumif With Some Conditions Based on String Values

Tags: excel

I have a table in my Excel that has column named '`Text`' (Column AJ). In that column I have few different sentences that contain the expression Quarterly 1, Quarterly 2 and on and on till 4. I want to sum the values in column AK (money values) based on the key words in the text column. I want to create some index table for each quarter that has the the some for each quarter.

note: sometimes its `quarterly 1` and sometimes it's `quarterly1`

for Example the cells should look like this:

```
bla bla bla Quaterly 1 bla bla
bla bla bla Quaterly1 bla bla
bla bla bla Quaterly2 bla tatata
bla bla bla Quaterly 3 bla
Quaterly 4 bla bla
```

Someone have any intersting ideas to manipulate Excel?

Comment: Is it `Quarterly #Number` with or without space between always? Or you have  variations like `Qtr1`?

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij Just "Quarterly 1" or "Quarterly1" . No other variations.

Comment: You can try something on the lines of `=SUMPRODUCT((SUBSTITUTE(AJ2:AJ1000," ","")="Quarterly1")+0,AK2:AK1000)` and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formula in E1: - credit to: shrivallabha.redij

```
=SUMPRODUCT((SUBSTITUTE(A:A," ","")=D1)+0,B:B)
```

[image]

**Update for bla bla:**

Since it will be contained within a sentence, I had to use search array on a control table. You can also achieve the end result with pivot.

Add a control column referencing to a control table in dotted line:

Array formula in C1: Ctrl+Shift+Enter to apply

```
{=INDEX(F$1:F$8,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(E$1:E$8,A1)),0))}
```

Formula in I1:

```
=SUMIF(C$1:C$9,H1,B$1:B$9)
```

[image]

Comment: It returns me value 0. in column A in your picture, as I said it contains not just Quaterly1, but can be also "bla bla bla Quaterly 1 bla bla".

Comment: edit: formula in E1, not E2. will it be bla blaQuaterly 1 as in bla and Quaterly combines without space?

Comment: it will with space from ble bla always

Comment: You can modify SUMPRODUCT like `=SUMPRODUCT(B:B,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D1,SUBSTITUTE(A:A," ","")))+0)`